# Update Mysql record using gridview with checkbox column

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, database, gridview

I have a table in mysql databse with a boolean column (or tinyint(1)). In my web application i used a gridview to view the data from that table and I used a checkbox field for the boolean column. Everything's ok till here. When I try to update a record, checking or unchecking the checkbox field using this query for the update:

```
UPDATE image SET `desc` = @desc, `ss` = @ss WHERE `id` = @id
```

the result is always the same: the **desc** field is correctly updated meanwhile the **ss** (boolean field) is always set to 0, even if maybe i set it to 1 or true. Any idea on how to do it? I paste the sqldatasource code below:

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dogservConnectionString %>" 
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM image WHERE `id` = @id" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dogservConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM image" 

    UpdateCommand="UPDATE image SET `desc` = @desc, `ss` = @ss WHERE `id` = @id">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="desc" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="path" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="name" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ss" Type="Object" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Please show us the code that calls this update

Comment: i used a sqldatasource and i set the update query in the wizzard setup. So i use gridview's edit property to edit my record

Comment: I can't help you with asp.net, but that `<asp:Parameter Name="ss" Type="Object" /> ` looks very suspicious to me. Type should be something like Int32 or bool

Comment: It actually works! By default that parameter was set like this so I didn't figure out that the error could be there. You can post the answer, or i delete my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't help you with asp.net, but that  looks very suspicious to me.
You tell us that your ss column is a tinyint so type should be something like Int32 or bool.